# How To Split a Generic Array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I want to mimic the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) functionality for generic arrays.

I have come up with this method which seems to work for doubles.

```
public static double[][] Split(this double[] vals, double t)
{
    List<double[]> ret = new List<double[]>();

    int last = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= vals.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != vals.Length && vals[i] != t)
            continue;

        int len = i - last - 1;
        if (len <= 0)
        {
            last = i;
            continue;
        }

        double[] arr = new double[len];
        Array.Copy(vals, last + 1, arr, 0, len);
        last = i;

        ret.Add(arr);
    }

    return ret.ToArray();
}
```

And this one for generics...

```
public static T[][] Split<T>(this T[] vals, T t) where T : EqualityComparer<T>
{
    List<T[]> ret = new List<T[]>();

    int last = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= vals.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != vals.Length && vals[i] != t)
            continue;

        int len = i - last - 1;
        if (len <= 0)
        {
            last = i;
            continue;
        }

        T[] arr = new T[len];
        Array.Copy(vals, last + 1, arr, 0, len);
        last = i;

        ret.Add(arr);
    }

    return ret.ToArray();
}
```

So, I have three questions:

1. Is there a better/generic-C# way of doing this?
2. How can I get the template method working? (I get an error on `vals[i] != t`) - Fixed now
3. How can I make this better (It is kind of ugly right now, IMO)

Example Usage:

```
double[] vals = new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6 };
double[][] res = vals.Split(0);

// res[0] = [1, 2]
// res[1] = [2, 3]
// res[2] = [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: questions #1 and #3 are not really appropriate here.  They're too subject.  On codereview it could be okay, although it would need some improvement.  It also needs to be working first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following generic extension method to split sequences by some separator. It uses default comparer to compare each item with separator.

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T separator)
{
    List<T> bucket = new List<T>();
    var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (comparer.Compare(item, separator) != 0)
        {
            bucket.Add(item);
            continue;
        }

        if (bucket.Any())
        {
            yield return bucket.ToArray();
            bucket = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    if (bucket.Any())        
        yield return bucket.ToArray();        
}
```

Usage:

```
double[] vals = new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6 };
double[][] res = vals.Split(0).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do it lazily, and over any sequence, and as an extension method. I'd also get rid of the `IComparable<T>` constraint - you're not using that here anyway. You *could* use `CompareTo` instead of trying to use `!=` (which as you can tell, doesn't work) but as you're only interested in *equality*, it makes more sense to use `EqualityComparer<T>`.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                                   T separator)
{
    List<T> currentList = new List<T>();
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(item, separator))
        {
            yield return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(currentList);
            currentList = new List<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            currentList.Add(item);
        }
    }
    yield return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(currentList);
}
```

Note that this *will* return empty collections if you have either the separator at the start or end, or repeated separators. Of course, you can always ignore those at the calling side:

```
var nonEmptySequences = original.Split(value)
                                .Where(sequence => sequence.Any());
```

Short but complete sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

public static class MoreExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>
        (this IEnumerable<T> source, T separator)
    {
        List<T> currentList = new List<T>();
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(item, separator))
            {
                yield return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(currentList);
                currentList = new List<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                currentList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        yield return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(currentList);
    }

}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] source = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6 };
        foreach (var group in source.Split(0).Where(x => x.Any()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(",", group));
        }
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
[1,2]
[2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

Comment: FYI he's ensuring that there are no empty entries, you aren't.

Comment: @Servy: As I'd just noted :) (`String.Split` doesn't by default, and it's easy to filter them out afterwards...)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the template method working? (I get an error on `vals[i] != t`)

The `!=` operator isn't going to be defined for any arbitrary type `T`.  However, you know that `T` imlements `IComparable<T>`, so leverage that:

```
vals[i].CompareTo(t) != 0
```

Comment: What about using `IEquatable<T>` or an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Both would be good ideas.  I focused on the smallest change needed to get his code working, not how I would implement it myself.